# Turning a string of numbers list into a list of integers tuple

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

I'm trying to turn a list of numbers into a integer tuple:

`Input: ['1 0', '2 3']`

`Output:(1,0),(2,3)`

What I've tried:

```
_input=['1 0', '2 3']
tuple=()
for i in _input:
    for j in i:
        j.replace(' ','')
    tuple.append(i)
print(_input)
```

Comment: `[tuple(int(i) for i in j.split() for j in your_list]`

Comment: don't use `input` as name, it's a built-in function.